# perform same percentage calculation with different range

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, math, css3pie

i am moving a image using a slider whose range is 0 to 100 percent it work perfect by getting the background image left according to slider value now i want to perform same function but slider have range -75 to 75 who can i calculate same left so that at slider value 75 it become equal to above slider value 100 i am week in Math please point me in right direction

hare is the code
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axtruo/qW8Db/10/)

```
     // when range from 0 to 100
 $( "#sliderAbove" ).slider({
   min: 0,
   max: 100,
   slide: function( event, ui ) {
       var backImgwidth = $("#backgroundImg").width();
       var left = (( backImgwidth / 100 ) * (ui.value)) ;
       $("#dragable").css("left",left);
   $( "#above" ).val(ui.value );
  }
```

Comment: -75 to 75 is the slider range and i want functionality 0-75 as 0-100

Comment: is this what u want...http://jsfiddle.net/jady/qW8Db/11/

Comment: yes i want that when i move sloder at 0 dragable image is at topleft corner and when slider at 75 image is at topright corner

Comment: posted an answer ..have a look

Comment: where you post answer iJay

Comment: try refreshing your page and scroll down

Comment: please be with me and take a look at this please http://jsfiddle.net/axtruo/qW8Db/15/

Comment: i want at 75 from 0 it cover 100% width

Comment: answer updated...have a look

Comment: thank you so much this is exactly what i want would you like to explain it too

Comment: k..i'll add explanation to answer..plz upvote and mark as answer

Comment: why divide by 125 not work if the background image have different width

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/axtruo/qW8Db/17/ please look at this

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/axtruo/qW8Db/17/ please look at this

Comment: ok...so the image width may change...u never mentioned dat in the question....anywaz give me some time

Comment: please take your time but try to found out i am waiting for your replay

Comment: ...i just updated the code and i hope its self explanatory. And plz don't comment further here. Comment under the answer if any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dragable").draggable();

    $("#sliderbelow").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 75,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            var backImgwidth = $("#backgroundImg").width();
            var draggableWidth = $('#dragable').width();

            var diff = Number(backImgwidth) - Number(draggableWidth);
            var factor = diff / 75;

            var left = (factor * (ui.value));

            $("#dragable").css("left", left);
            $("#below").val(ui.value);
        }
    });

});
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jady/qW8Db/19/)

Comment: thanks for this and if i need your help in future how can i contact you

Comment: shoot me a mail at jay3dec@gmail.com